# nosetest not finding tests on cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, nose, nosetests

I have a set of unit tests files created in python with unittest as the import.
Running nosetests on both the terminal of MacOSX and on the cmd.exe of Windows 7, it finds the tests and runs them.

Trying to execute nosetests under Cygwin does not find any tests to run.

All three cases use the same version of Python (3.4) and the same version of nose(1.3.6). Also, none of the files are marked as executable

I suspect that is something environmental on cygwin. Does anyone know that do I need to do?

Answer (score -1):

If you only have a single file with tests, you can launch it like this: `nosetests tests.py`

Comment: Had more than one file. At then end, I just stopped using Cygwin and run a Linux VM on my Win rig.